# how to code array initialisation for performance?

Tags: php, arrays, initialization

my question is easy

is that ... :

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., x); //x is a huge number for the theory
```

...faster, lower or is it the same speed than :

```
$arr[] = 1;
$arr[] = 2;
$arr[] = 3;
$arr[] = 4;
$arr[] = 5;
...
$arr[] = x;
```

?

I think the second way of coding is easy to alter especially if there are multi-dim arrays.
But is this one altering the speed of processing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By rough testing, the second method is twice as slow as the first one but unless you are using a very large array (100,000+ elements) or initializing the array a lot of times (1000s of times per second), the difference is negligible.

For syntactic purposes, refer to Berk's answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the first form array has constant size. But second initialization method resizes array on every assignment.

Second one will be slower.

I recommend to init like this:

```
$arr = array(1,
             2,
             3,
             4,
             ...
             x);
```

You you can take advatages from both.